# django staticfiles with multiple apps

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have two apps:

foo and bar

the project structure like below, how do I make sure app styles do not conflict? Running manage.py collectstatic dissolves either one of the files currently... The admin app is imported to the collected directory within an 'admin' folder however my app static data gets imported directly into the main directory thus overwriting other apps if duplicate files are found

```
/Project
   /foo
      /static
         /css
            /style.css
      /views.py
      /models.py
      /urls.py
   /bar
      /static
         /css
            /style.css
      /views.py
      /models.py
      /urls.py
   /urls.py
   /manage.py
   /settings.py
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't do that this way. With or without staticfiles/collectstatic, djando would ever serve one of the two `style.css` files. Just prepend the app name inside `static/`. See also how `django/contrib/(admin|auth|...)/static` are laid out

```
Project
|-- foo
|   |-- static
|   |   `-- foo
|   |       `-- css
|   |           `-- style.css
|   |-- views.py
|   |-- models.py
|   `-- urls.py
|-- bar
|   |-- static
|   |   `-- bar
|   |       `-- css
|   |           `-- style.css
|   |-- views.py
|   |-- models.py
|   `-- urls.py
|-- urls.py
|-- manage.py
`-- settings.py
```

Comment: what if the both have same css files, how to keep them at one place?

Comment: One of them is overridden by the other. That's why you have to namespace your app's static files, and that's how you can actually override other apps and eggs static files if needed. At least that was the case 7 years ago...